# Error when using bs4 in python: Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
File "/home/x/Desktop/Python Programs/Web Scraping tutorial/ccrealweb.py", line 8, in <module>     company_name = jobs.find('a', class_ = 'gtmJobListingPostedBy').a.text  
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/bs4/element.py", line 2253, in __getattr__     raise 
AttributeError( AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?
```

When trying to run some basic web scraping code,I get these errors. I've had a look around at other forums, and haven't seen something like my particular code (or at least that I can understand). Please help, as I am thoroughly clueless right now.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

html_text = requests.get('https://www.reed.co.uk/jobs/python-jobs').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'lxml')
jobs = soup.find_all('article', class_ = 'job-result-card')
for job in jobs:
    company_name = jobs.find('a', class_ = 'gtmJobListingPostedBy').text
    skills = jobs.find('p', class_ = 'job-result-description__details').text
    published_date = jobs.find('div', class_ = 'job-result-heading__posted-by').text.strip()
    print('Company name:', company_name)
    print('Skills:', skills)
    print(published_date, '\n')
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation of the `for job in jobs` loop.

Comment: It's always suspicous when a for loop doesn't use the iteration variable. Don't you mean `job.find()` instead of `jobs.find()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you do

```py
for job in jobs
```

then you have to do **job**.find and not **jobs**.find
Your code works very well afterwards.

```
Company name: Marshall Wolfe
Skills: 
Python software Engineer - Software Developer Our client a growing technology consultancy based in Suffolk, is recruiting the services of a Software Engineer on a permanent basis. This role would suit either a graduate level developer looking for their...
                
30 November 2022 by Marshall Wolfe 
....
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I would give you an upvote thing, but I don't have enough reputation. Have a good day!

Comment: Just made the exact same mistake. If I could facepalm on the internet I would, but I'd just like to thank you again.